# I have a problem with SPI_connect (), Postgresql in C

Tags: c, postgresql

I have a problem with
PostgreSQL `SPI_connect()` in C. The problem is that I get the `SPI_ERROR_CONNECT` value and I don't know why. Do you know just in case in which cases the `SPI_ERROR_CONNECT` value appears in `SPI_connect()`?

I have already tried to make the code work but it still gives me the value `SPI_ERROR_CONNECT`.

The part of code with the error is:

```
initStringInfo( &query );
initStringInfo( &cols );

foreach( cell, candidates ) /* foreach cell in candidates */
{
    int i;
    IndexCandidate* idxcd = (IndexCandidate*)lfirst( cell );
    get_columnnames(idxcd);

    if( !idxcd->idxused )
        continue;

    /* pfree() the memory allocated for the previous candidate. FIXME: Avoid
     * meddling with the internals of a StringInfo, and try to use an API.
     */
    if( cols.len > 0 )
    {
        pfree( cols.data );
        cols.data = NULL;
    }


    appendStringInfo( &query, "select n_distintic from pg_stats where ");

    for (i = 0; i < idxcd->ncols; ++i)
    {

        appendStringInfo( &cols, "attname=%s%d", (i>0?"OR":""), idxcd->varattnombres[i]);


    }/* foreach col in varattno*/


    /* FIXME: Mention the column names explicitly after the table name. */
    appendStringInfo( &query, "%s;", cols.data);

    elog(INFO,"QUERY:%s", query.data);
    elog(INFO,"LONGITUD:%d", query.len);


    if( query.len > 0 ) /* if we generated any SQL */
    {
        if( SPI_connect() == SPI_OK_CONNECT )
        {

            if( SPI_execute( query.data, true, 0 ) != SPI_OK_SELECT )
                    elog( WARNING, "IND ADV: SPI_execute failed while select." );

            else /* SPI_OK_SELECT*/
            {

                proc=SPI_processed;
                tupdesc=SPI_tuptable->tupdesc;
                SPITupleTable *tuptable=SPI_tuptable;
                char buf[8192];
                int i,j;
                for(j=0;j<proc;j++)
                {
                    /*cada fila*/
                    HeapTuple tuple=tuptable->vals[j];
                    for (i=0,buf[0]=0;i<tupdesc->natts;i++)
                    {
                        /* cada columna de cada fila*/
                        char *data;
                        data=SPI_getvalue(tuple,tupdesc,i);

                        snprintf(buf+strlen(buf),sizeof(buf)-strlen(buf),"%s %s",data,(i==tupdesc->natts)?"": "|");
                    }

                    elog(INFO,"EXECQ:%s",buf);  
                    strcpy(idxcd->ndistinct,buf);

                }

            }

            if( SPI_finish() != SPI_OK_FINISH )
                elog( WARNING, "IND ADV: SPI_finish failed while select." );
        }
        else /* SPI_connect() != SPI_OK_CONNECT*/
            elog( WARNING, "IND ADV: SPI_connect failed while select." );
    }   

    /* TODO: Propose to -hackers to introduce API to free a StringInfoData . */
    if ( query.len > 0 )
        pfree( query.data );


} /* foreach cell in candidates */
```

I expect the value `SPI_OK_CONNECT`, but the actual result is `SPI_ERROR_CONNECT`.

Comment: What version are you using?  The documentation indicates the behavior of this function is pretty different depending on version.

Comment: I would attach a debugger and check what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

so it's possible to get a more detailed error message with `SPI_result_code_string`:

```
if ((rc = SPI_connect()) != SPI_OK_CONNECT) {
    elog(ERROR, "SPI_connect failed: %s", SPI_result_code_string(rc));
}
```

That may help you uncover the source of the problem. Good luck!

Comment: That will just return `SPI_ERROR_CONNECT` as string.